# How to integrate multiple Shiny apps into a single website using a shared database?

Tags: r, shiny, integration, visualization

I have a collection of multiple R Shiny apps that are currently standalone applications. Each one reads in a set of 8 CSV files and visualizes the data in various ways. All of the apps use the same set of 8 source data files.

Now, I'm aiming to create a website that integrates all of these Shiny apps into a single, unified platform, with a database backend that will host the 8 datasets, as well as store operations performed by users (e.g. I want to add a dashboard to display user-selected analyses performed using the apps).

I've reviewed info available online about doing this, but while I've found info on tangential topics, e.g. embedding a single Shiny app in a website, integrating multiple Shiny apps into a single app (not website), etc., I haven't found much info about how to integrate multiple standalone apps via a unified website and database.

I appreciate any suggestions to direct me to strategies that will allow me to unify my Shiny apps into a functional website with database backend. Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Shiny is supposed to be a one HTML page dashboard. If you want multiple sections in your dashboard, why don't you use 'navbarPage' or Tabsets ? 
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/navbar-example.html
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Rituraj.

Comment: Hi @BobLoblaw, I am facing similar situation now where I has multiple shinyapps and want to integrate to a single app. Did you found any solution for it other than using Navbars and Tab Panels? The individuals apps has their own navbars and tab panels so i was wondering, if you found any alternative solution.